# No way to tell if an answer has been accepted on mobile browser

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, accepted-answer, mobile-web

I can't see what answer has been accepted on a question with an accepted answer on my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Y S5360, Android version 2.3.5); I assume it is the one on top.
This isn't a major problem, but it's something that is 'faulty' with the system.
Is this problem just happening on Android phones, or even just my version of Android?

**EDIT:**
I've been notified that there is in fact a green tick symbolizing the answer has been accepted. However, there is no way (that I know of) that you can tell that the answer has been accepted (from the main answer screen).

Questions with upvoted answers have a green tinge in them, but I can't see anything that tells you, "I'm answered!" As you can see, this caused some confusion on my part.

Comment: No repro on Chrome for Android 4 on an HTC sensation - there's a little green tick below the vote down arrow just as there would be on the main site.

Comment: @Rory I see the problem here, I'll edit the question.

Comment: For me, where there the number of answers is displayed, if one is accepted, it is filled in with a green shade

Comment: Once again, I was muddling everything up. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mobile site uses similar colours to the desktop site to indicate this on the question list and uses a similar tick icon on the question page:

[image: Accepted in question list]

In the above image the first question in the list has one non accepted answer but the second in the list has 3 answers, of which one is accepted.  This is shown by the green shading on the answer count.

[image: Accepted in question view]

On the actual question page the accepted status is indicated by the green tick box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm declining this at this time because we're working on a larger mobile design review.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231442/please-update-the-mobile-theme-for-meta-se) as well then. :)