# Please update the mobile theme for Meta.SE

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, mobile-web

Currently the mobile theme (for Windows Phone at least) is identical to the Meta Stack Overflow theme. Differentiating them at a glance is very difficult; you need to look for clues like the top bar (which may be scrolled out of view) or the link in the address bar of the phone's browser.

It's also almost impossible to differentiate the sites in the tab preview on the phone:

[image]

(note that the page title is obscured so it's not easily visible).

This is how the actual page looks in each site.

[image]

[image]

Comment: All the mobile sites use the same theme

Comment: Never noticed that, @mhlester; they do indeed.

Comment: That said, it wouldn't hurt to update the theme to be more generic than the one that currently screams Stack Overflow

Comment: @mhlester I hadn't noticed that. I think it's probably worth modifying the top used ones (like the trilogy metas, plus Meta.SE) as they are the most likely to be bookmarked (and used) in some way on a mobile device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile optimized version of Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/mobile-optimized-version-of-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Declining as there are no plans to differentiate the sites on mobile (see e.g. the mobile apps).

Comment: But you could update the `<title>` tag for the mobile sites to put the site's abbreviation first or something similar.